# Can I get a list of the source files being knitted, from within knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

Let's say I have main.Rmd:

````
Mainfile
================

```{r child="child1.Rmd"}
```

```{r child="child2.Rmd"}
```

```{r}
print("These documents were knitted:")
Something_goes_here()
```
````

What can I put in place of `Something_goes_here()` to get a list of child1.Rmd, child2.Rmd, and main.Rmd?

In general, is there some way to access knitr's guts from within a document being knitted?

Edit; added to clarify:

I'd like a way for a knitted document to be able to tell by itself what files were knitted. My idea is to have a document create a listing of references at the end for the files used to create the document. I could then include that document as a child document in all of our reports so they'd be automatically self-documenting.

Comment: You want to look at knitr's _guts_?!?  You're a monster!

Comment: maybe `x <- c("child1.Rmd", "child2.Rmd")`, `child=x[1]`, `child=x[2]`, then `print(x)`

Comment: Hah! Well I guess that's a literal answer to what I asked :)

Comment: I'd like a way for a knitted document to be able to tell by itself what files were knitted. My idea is to have a document create a listing of references at the end for the files used to create the document. I could then include that document as a child document in all of our reports so they'd be automatically self-documenting.

Comment: unfortunately `knitr` does not store these filenames anywhere